# Silverlight Identifying Info

Tags: silverlight, client, identification

I am currently working on a Silverlight application that talks to a server application. I am trying to come up with any info that I can use to identify the client when it connects. I obviously have the IP on the server side but that is about it. I was planning on having the client send a message with its ID info as part of the connection process. The issue I am having is that Silverlight without elevated privileges doesn't have access to anything useful to identify the client. I tried computer name, username, etc, but they are all things Silverlight doesn't have access to without elevated privileges or an external service. Is there anything I am missing? Is there anything I can get to that would help identify the client?

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating a "fingerprint" based on plugins, screen size, etc. Here is a j-query plugin that claims to do just that:

https://github.com/carlo/jquery-browser-fingerprint